# Java: Private variables used in inherited methods

Tags: java, private

I'm fairly new to Java, and according to my knowledge, variable drawingChar in class Shape is private, so it isn't inherited by class Test, but since setDrawingChar() is a public function, it is inherited.

```
public class Shape {

    private char drawingChar = '*'; // private var

    public void setDrawingChar(char drawingChar) {
        this.drawingChar = drawingChar;
    }
} 
public class Test extends Shape{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t2 = new Test();
    t2.setDrawingChar('*'); // call setDrawingChar on a Test obj
    }
}
```

In class Test, somehow I'm allowed to call setDrawingChar() on a Test object, but isn't it true that Test doesn't inherit drawingChar? If so, what is **this.drawingChar** referring to in object t2's case?

Comment: It does inherit `drawingChar`. `private` means you can't directly access it outside of its class. It doesn't mean that it doesn't exist.

Comment: It's not, and that's why you have a setter right there - you have no ideas what private members there exist, but you can still set the drawing chair.

Comment: Ohh, so private has nothing to do with inheriting...Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subclasses will inherit any `public` or `protected` variables or methods, and can choose to leave them alone or override them (in the case of methods). That's why you can call the method `setDrawingChar`, it checks `Test` for any method by that name, and then checks its superclasses for an implementation. It finds the implementation from `Shape` and executes that.

Note that you would not be able to use the `Shape` variable `drawingChar`, since the `private` scope is only limited to other `Shape` objects and not their subclasses

More info on `public`, `private`, and `protected` at the [javadocs website for access control](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).